# C99999 format in java to be used in sql

Tags: java, sql, zerofill

i have a number with format "C99999"

i need import it to sql

i try this

```
while (rs.next()){
         int s=rs.getInt("Number");
        s++;

        String n = String.format("%05d",s);
        view.txtcustomernumber.setText(n);
```

how to add "C" into this format and the data type in mysql is int

Comment: Why are you trying to import a String "C00002" as a number? It is not a number.  Do you want to discard the leading "C" and store only the numeric part?

Comment: no, i need to store the"C" too

Comment: Then you can't use a numeric column. It has to be placed into a VARCHAR column.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `"C%05d"` as the format string.

Comment: i alread try that but i get some error when add it to sql

this is the error " java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "C00002"

Comment: Okay, do you have a stack trace for that exception?